# Running Xcode DocC documentation via Apache locally on macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, docc

Xcode 13's DocC documentation archives can be hosted using a custom Apache `.htaccess` file as described in [Distributing Documentation to External Developers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-documentation-to-external-developers) and [Host and automate your DocC documentation - WWDC21](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10236).

What are the steps to get that set up for the [SlothCreator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/slothcreator_building_docc_documentation_in_xcode) example project on a macOS / a M1 Mac so you can look at the documentation in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Get the [SlothCreator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/slothcreator_building_docc_documentation_in_xcode) example project and build the documentation archive in Xcode or the command line as described in [Distributing Documentation to External Developers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-documentation-to-external-developers)
- Install httpd via Homebrew:

  ```
  brew install httpd
  ```
- Copy `SlothCreator.doccarchive` to `/opt/homebrew/var/www/` (paths are for M1 Macs)
- Edit `/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`:

  - Allow `AllowOverride All` for the DocumentRoot Directory
  - Enable `LoadModule rewrite_module`
- Edit `/opt/homebrew/var/www/.htaccess` and use the example configuration as provided by Apple in [Distributing Documentation to External Developers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-documentation-to-external-developers)
- Restart Apache: `sudo apachectl restart`
- You should now be able to open `http://localhost:8080/documentation/slothcreator/` and `http://localhost:8080/tutorials/slothcreator/`

Enjoy!

Comment: One could also use the httpd built into macOS; I didn't think about that when writing this.